# Visual Studio doesn't save changes on build unless the project is selected

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've got a really frustrating error in my Visual Studio 2017 Winforms project.

Unless I have SPECIFICALLY selected the project by clicking on its name, and then pressing start (to debug), it will fail to load my changes that I've just made to a file (Even if I've specifically saved it prior)

(Also when I build it., it stuffs up the indenting / curly braces as you will see at the end of the video.)

I have tried cleaning / rebuilding / deleting bin folders (which works, but only the first time) / closing and reopening VS.

Would be seriously glad of any help!

[View video here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhtcj7czak2jmr7/Untitled%2027.avi?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here! It was the Resharper Patch by Dim@ster that was causing the issue. So weird!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21580789/4910205